# losing data entered in dataview C#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I am using `Visual  C# 2008` to make a application that takes the data from `textboxes` and displays it in `datagridview` in another form the conforming make it entered to the database.
I send the data using `dataTable` with a function entered the data without any symentic error but when I call the other for the `datagridview` comes empty and the database comes empty. When I duplicate a primary key it gives an error stating `"cannot duplicate primary key"`.

This is the code for the function that transfers that `datatable`

```
public DataTable showout() {
    DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("رقم المتسلسل");
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("رقم الحساب");
    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("أسم الحساب");

    dtab.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dtab.Columns.Add(dc2);
    dtab.Columns.Add(dc3);

   // Create an array for the values. 
   object[] newRow = new object[3];

    // Set the values of the array.
     string s = numb.Text;


     newRow[0] =numb.Text;
     newRow[1] = textBox5.Text;
     newRow[2] =note.Text;


     DataRow row;

     dtab.BeginLoadData();


     // Add the new row to the rows collection.
     row = dtab.LoadDataRow(newRow, true);

    return dtab;
}
```

this is the code that I call the function in the other From

```
private void Cashagree_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.DataSource = ch.showout();
}
```

the second datagrid entering function its in the same class

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dataGridView1.Visible = true;
       dataGridView1.DataSource = showout();

        entering(true);
    }
```

and this is the entering to the database

```
   public void entering(bool bl)
      {try{
        if (bl)
        {

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                DateTime Date = DateTime.Today;


                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Accont(Account_ID,Account_Name,Owners,Curency,Curncytype,Depet,Credet_devet,Date,Note) VALUES (@AccountID, @AccountName, @Owner, @Curncy,@Curncytype,@Depet,@Cridetdevet,@Date,@Note)");
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountID",numb.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", comboBox1.SelectedText.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owner", owner.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Curncy", curency.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Curncytype", curncyval.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depet", Depet.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cridetdevet", textBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", note.Text);
                connection.Open();//Owner
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();}}
    }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);}
```

the conforming from the another form

```
   private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ch.entering(true);
            Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solve it by the sending the `DataTable dt` from the `first Form cash` to the `second Form cashagree` as a prameter by calling the method that return datagridview 
 in cash form I wrote this:

```
  cashagree gc2 = cashagree(showout());
```

in cashagree form I wrote this

```
  DataTable dt = new DstsTsble();
 public cashagree(DataTable d2){
   dt =d2;

 }
 and in the load of `cashagree_Load` I asign the datagridview datasoure 

   private void Cashagree_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[0].IsNull(dt.Columns[0]))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There no primary key");
            Close();
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;// Iwantn't all the datatable so I diapple some Columns
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;



      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the dtab.LoadDataRow, you should be using the dtab.Rows.Add(datarow) method.
An example of how to do this:

```
public DataTable showout()
{
  DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
  // More efficient way of adding the columns with types:
  dtab.Columns.Add("رقم المتسلسل", typeof(String));
  dtab.Columns.Add("رقم الحساب", typeof(String));
  dtab.Columns.Add("أسم الحساب", typeof(String));
  /*
  DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("رقم المتسلسل");
  DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("رقم الحساب");
  DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("أسم الحساب");

  dtab.Columns.Add(dc1);
  dtab.Columns.Add(dc2);
  dtab.Columns.Add(dc3);
  */

  // Create a new row using the .NewRow method
  DataRow datRow = dtab.NewRow();
  datRow["رقم المتسلسل"] = numb.Text;
  datRow["رقم الحساب"] = textBox5.Text;
  datRow["أسم الحساب"] = note.Text;

  // Add the new row to the DataTable
  dtab.Rows.Add(datRow);

 return dtab;
}
```

Reference:

[How to: Add Rows to a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx)
[Adding Data to a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z16c79x4.aspx)

Comment: thank you for advice but the `problem not at adding row` because when I add a `string` in the rows it shown in the `datagrid`

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was the issue because of this sentence:
"I send the data using dataTable with a function entered the data without any symentic error but when I call the other for the datagridview comes empty and the database comes empty." I"ll have a look at the duplicate primary key issue

Comment: the duplicating issue is happen when I enter the row again because I didn't see it at the database

Comment: In the code that you showed, there is no second table or database, could you amend your question to show that table and how you are adding the second row please?

Comment: I found subanswer in this Question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830824/c-sharp-winforms-how-do-i-retrieve-data-from-a-textbox-on-one-form-via-another  now it shown in the next form but the database is empty

Comment: Are you retrieving the data from the database at any point and show it in the GridView on the next form? So setting the GridView's DataSource to a DataTable which is filled with the data from the database table?