# Losing data and gridview C#

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, datatable

I have a program by VC2008  that send dataTable I sended it using the constractor I solve it help at [losing data entered in dataview C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869681/losing) -    to `datagridview` in another `Form`  it work fine but I want to send only the new row I tried to copy using `ImportRrow` it to another datatable but it gives Form2 Blank.

and I send the data as datatable by method as following:

```
   public DataTable showout2()
    {
        DataTable dtab = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("رقم المتسلسل");
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("رقم الحساب");
        DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("أسم الحساب");
        DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("المالك");
        DataColumn dc5 = new DataColumn("قيمة");
        DataColumn dc6 = new DataColumn("نوع العملة");
        DataColumn dc7 = new DataColumn("الدائن");
        DataColumn dc8= new DataColumn("المدين");
        DataColumn dc9= new DataColumn("تاريخ");
        DataColumn dc10 = new DataColumn("تفاصيل");
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc2);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc3);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc4);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc5);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc6);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc7);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc8);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc9);
        dtab.Columns.Add(dc10);
        DateTime date = new DateTime();

        date = DateTime.Now;

        // Create an array for the values. 
        object[] newRow = new object[10];
```

Set the values of the array.

```
        string s = numb.Text;
        newRow[0] = numb.Text;
        newRow[1] = Account_numb.Text;
        newRow[2] = Account_nam.Text;
        newRow[3] = owner.Text;
        newRow[4] = curency.Text;
        newRow[5] = comboBox1.Text;
        newRow[6] = Depet.Text;
        newRow[7] = cridet.Text;
        newRow[8] = date.ToString();
        newRow[9] = note.Text;
```

declare DataRow and adding it to DataTable

```
        DataRow row;

        dtab.BeginLoadData();

        // Add the new row to the rows collection.
        row = dtab.LoadDataRow(newRow, true);

        return dtab;

    }
```

I transfer the data from `Form` as following

```
   cashagree fm = cashagree(shouwout2());
```

I copy the datarow in constractor take datatable as prameter as following:

```
public Cashagree(DataTable d2)
    {


        dt.ImportRow(d2.Rows[0]);


    }
```

here I assign the datasource and mange the secound datagridview

```
    private void Cashagree_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i != dt.Rows.Count; i++){
                label1.Text= dt.Rows[i].ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[i].ToString()))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This is empty");
                }
                }
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
             dataGridView.Columns[3].Visible = false;
            dataGridView.Columns[4].Visible = false;
             dataGridView.Columns[5].Visible = false;

            dataGridView.Columns[6].Visible = false;

           dataGridView.Columns[7].Visible = false;
       }

        catch (Exception w) { MessageBox.Show("Error" + w.StackTrace); }
        }
```

thank you for helping

Comment: Did you set/refresh the databinding in the DGV?

Comment: what you mean by refresh ?

Comment: where and when do you set the data binding? (Assuming the DGV is data bound)

Comment: did you meaning asign it to datasource?

Comment: the editting is space to separate code from text sorry

Comment: But why Iam  losing the conection between the forms?

Comment: Are you closing a Form?

Comment: No I make the child as dialog I call it using `ShowDialog()`

Comment: the only way I found to send the `DataRow`  as `DataTable` I want to send it as a single Row